# Optimize comparison in R

Tags: r, performance, optimization, comparison

I'm still new to R programming and I need to optimize some portion of my code. I'll explain how it works below.

#### My current code too slow

```
myfunc <- function(dt){
    indexes = which(dt$time == CURRENT)

    for(i in indexes){
        # columns foo, bar & baz are used to build rowname
        # and colnames
        linename = paste(dt$foo[i], "_", dt$bar[i], sep="")
        colname  = dt$baz[i]

        # related_var is the name of an other global var
        # and value is the corresponding value in
        # related_var[linename, colname]
        dt$value[i] = get(dt$related_var[i])[[linename, colname]]
    }
    return(dt)
}
```

#### How do I use it ?

This is not my portion of the code so I just simplified it

```
CURRENT = 0
MAX     = 1000
for(i in 1:MAX){
    doSomeStuffOnGlobalVars()
    # get datas from global var for this CURRENT
    dt = myfunc(dt)
    CURRENT = CURRENT + 1
}
```

#### Some explanation

This function is called for all values of `CURRENT (like 1,2,3,4,5,... 1000)` and we want to update `$value` in `dt` for every row that match `dt$time == CURRENT` and the thing is that the variables "varname" are modified every `CURRENT`

```
dt : a data.table ordered by time in the form of
    foo   bar   baz   time   related_var   value
    1     1   "toto"  1      "varname"      NA
    1     2   "toto"  1      "varname"      NA
    2     1   "tata"  1      "varname"      NA
    2     8   "toto"  1      "varname"      NA
    ...

related_var : contain the name of a global data.frame which have its 
    colnames defined by baz in dt 
    rownames defined by a combination of foo & bar (foo_bar) in dt


example of "varname" variable:
          toto   tata
    1_1    1.6    2
    1_2    42   1337
    ...    ...    ...
    10_10    3.14   1.61
```

I already made some changes (I used `data.frame` before `data.table`, or `eval(parse(...))`) but this is still pretty slow (around 5s for dt with ~ 5000 rows), I'd like to know how I can optimize this, if you have ideas (R or pure algorithmic)

N.B. Tell me if its too cryptic

EDIT: I've found that the slow part is `dt$value[i] = get(dt$related_var[i])[[linename, colname]]` and it becomes much faster if I do a simple allocation like `justAvar = get(dt$related_var[i])[[linename, colname]]` so my question is now: "how R is going through indexes ? If I wanted to go to index=15 does R goes through all 14 previous elements ?"

Comment: At first glance, I think you can move this - `linename = paste(dt$foo[i], "_", dt$bar[i], sep="")` - outside of the loop, because `paste` and `[` are vectorized. And not related to optimization, but it would be more idiomatic to pass `CURRENT` as a parameter to `myfunc`, rather than depending on scoping rules to find it in a parent environment.

Comment: As far as I can see you don’t need the `for` loop inside the function at all (*maybe* for the last statement, but even that can be vectorised using a combination of `mget` and `lapply`).

Answer (score 0):

First, I would precompute linename, I suspect it is pretty much computed for a whole data table. Will use *data.table* reference magic. Second, inline and simplify the function. Last, use *data.table* [i,j,by] approach

```
dt <- ...

dt[, linename := paste(foo, "_", bar, sep="")]

CURRENT <- 0
MAX     <- 1000
for(i in 1:MAX) {
    doSomeStuffOnGlobalVars()
    # get datas from global var for this CURRENT

    dt[time == CURRENT, value := get(related_var)[[linename, baz]]]
    CURRENT <- CURRENT + 1
}
```

UPDATE

Useful read: http://www.r-bloggers.com/strategies-to-speedup-r-code/

UPDATE II

might as well set key for dt before the loop

```
setkey(dt, time)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example with linename, it works well but I have an error `recursive indexing failed at level 2` when I try to put more levels in  `dt[time == CURRENT, value := get(related_var)[[tried_other_level]][[linename, baz]]]` is there a way to go deep like `foo$bar$baz$toto$tata$lorem$['ipsum','dolor']` ? Just to know

Comment: @user3482164 Frankly, I don't know, good discussion seems to be at http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Recursive-indexing-failed-at-level-2-td2269338.html. You might want to move on and ask another question with code/data sample etc